# Ionic & Angular - Ion Datetime Design on iOS

Tags: android, ios, angular, datetime, ionic-framework

#### Context

I am facing a problem with Ionic + Angular + Capacitor + iOS. It's related with the `ion-datetime` iOS component design and according to my research there is a possible workaround to match it like Android devices.

#### Problem

The problems starts when the ion-datetime is implemented and apllied to iOS devices. If we want this component iOS design to match the Android design the documentation tell us to pass a `mode` attibute with the value `md`. Here's HTML an example:

```
<ion-datetime mode="md">/ion-datetime>
```

And another example for both HTML and TS:

```
pickerOptions: any = {
    mode: "md",
};

<ion-datetime [pickerOptions]="pickerOptions"></ion-datetime>
```

However this documented approach it's not having the desirable outcome. Therefore the iOS component still haves a curved wheel instead of a flat sheet. Let's take a look on a visual explanation.

#### Visual Explanation

As explained before both iOS and Android devices should now have the exact same design because we have setted the `mode` attribute to `md`. As we can see on the example image this is clearly not the case. iOS component design is still acting like some sort of curved wheel. Continuing to be very different from the android device.

[image]

Comment: Hi Grinnex. We're pretty strict here about Q/A separation. If you find yourself with an answer in the future, please write a question first as if you did not have an answer, and then add a self-answer. I've split this using the Community Wiki option (see below), so it's all done here, unless you want to re-post the answer for yourself (that would be fine).

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author, in order to move it to the answer space)*.

The solution to fix this issue is quite simple. However it will impact all Ionic components design because we are going to set the full `Ionic Module` to be just and only `md` (Material Design). So please be aware that everything related to frontend will be overwritten to possess Android design. To make this solution/workaround happen we will have just to manipulate the file "app.module.ts".

**#1 App Module TS (Ionic Project)**

```
...

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot({
            mode: 'md',
        }),
    ]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

And that's it! The iOS `ion-datetime` component design will now become exactly like Android component design. Please don't forget that this will cause all ionic components to be overwritten with a material design.

### References

- [https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/splash-screen)
- [https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/picker#pickeroptions](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/1627#issuecomment-650835957)
- https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/16717